# Where to ask case-specific questions about Android & fonts?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a specific list of fonts. Some are available in OTF files, others are available only in TTF files, whilst some are available in both. I want to install as many of them as possible (there are only about 5 in the list) on a smartphone with a specific Android version on it.

I want to ask, for each font listed, whether I should use TTF or OTF (where applicable), and how compatible said file type of said font is with this version of Android.

Nothing too complicated: just for each item, all I would need is either "OTF" or "TTF" and a short description of how compatible it would be for the version of Android I'd mention.

However, I'm not sure where to ask this question; which site would be best?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://android.stackexchange.com/ sounds like what you'd want.

---

This is in fact the case because you are dealing with androids and font files. There isn't any Fonts Stack Exchange, so the first place to look would probably be the [Android Stack Exchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/). Now the first thing you probably see when you go there is:

> Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for enthusiasts and power users of the Android operating system.

At first glance this site doesn't actually appear to fit you, but maybe there's still hope. In the [Help Center](https://android.stackexchange.com/help) of the site, specifically the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page, it says

> If your question generally covers...
>
> - Using your Android device
> - Using a particular app on your Android device
> - Trying to solve an error or other issue in using your Android device
>
> then this is the right place to ask.

You could say that your question is about "Using your Android device," so it seems like it could fit.

On the same page, there is a list of what is explicitly off-topic:

> Please note the following topics are expressly ***off-topic*** here:
>
> - Developing/programming for Android (please ask these questions on Stack Overflow)
> - Marketing your Android app or doing market research
> - Issues with the Google Play Store (or any other app marketplace) from the point of view of a developer or publisher
> - Questions asking the community to find or recommend something for you (a device, app, ROM, website, etc), including what to buy and
>     where to buy it
> - Speculative questions, like "When will X be available in my country?" or "Why does Company X do this?"
> - Legal questions, such as "Will X void my warranty?"
> - Android-independent questions, such as "Does Carrier X have prepaid plans?"

Your question does not appear to fit any item of this list, so I'd say you're good to [post the question there](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)!